# grouping of strings with 1 mismatch

Tags: python, string, hierarchical-clustering

I have a set of DNA sequences and I would like to group them i.e clustering based on similarity. The file looks like

```
ATGCATGCATGCATGC
ATGCATGCATGCATGC
ATGCATGCATGCATGC
ATGCATGCATGCATGT
ATGCATGCATGCATGT
TTGCATGCATGCATGC
TTGCATGCATGCATGC
TTGCATGCATGCATGC
TTGCATGCATGCATGC
TTGCATGCATGCATGC
```

cat File_Name.txt | sort | uniq -c

```
  3 ATGCATGCATGCATGC
  2 ATGCATGCATGCATGT
  5 TTGCATGCATGCATGC
```

With this I got the number and the string, which is a kind of clustering. Now i can filter the clusters based on the number of strings in each cluster.

But I I want to allow one mismatch while grouping of the data ( In this case all the reads fall into one group ), I would like to know what is the best way.

I could compare all the sequences against each other and calculate hamming distance and group the reads with hamming distance 0 or 1 together but it is computationally intensive.

I would like to know if there is any other way of doing it.

Comment: How many sequences are you matching, ie is `O(?)` important or runtime for few sequences?

Comment: It depends. May be 10000 sequences.

Comment: Say I have three sequences, (ATGC, AGGC, TGGC), should AGGC group with ATGC or TGGC?

Comment: @satoru...I did not think of this ambiguity. My ultimate goal is to reduce the number of clusters. Then I thought of doing one mismatch grouping. For now I can ignore them I mean keep them separate.

Comment: @gthmgeeky That is what he is asking :)

Comment: @gthmgeeky I think you need to clarity this

Comment: @satoru..It is OK to ignore the ambiguous strings which may cluster with more than one string. Keep a count of strings which are ambiguous.